# How do we talk about classes that do not inherit from the `Class` class in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, class, oop

[BasicObject](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/BasicObject.html), as far as I have read, is the parent class of all other classes in Ruby. However, it's not until further down in the hierarchy where the `Class` class is actually defined. As such, I'm having a hard time understanding how `BasicObject` can be a class at all.

Is the difference here just that there's a difference between a ruby `Class` in an abstract, object-oriented sense as opposed to classes that are actually instances of `Class`? Or is the hierarchy actually set up in a way where `BasicObject` is in fact an instance of `Class`? I feel pretty sure that's not the case.

If there are two meanings for the word "class" in Ruby, I feel like I lack the language to discuss the two types. If this is indeed the case, what can I call a class that is not an instance of `Class`?

Comment: Want to be more confused? `Class`'s superclass is `Module` but `Module`'s class is `Class` so `Module` is a `Module` and a `Class` just as a `Class` is a `Class` and a `Module`. But while `Module` is an instance of the class `Class` you cannot have an instance of the class `Module`. [Docs showing class Diagram](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Class.html) This is all handled through anonymous metaclasses (`singleton` or `eigen`) so while `BasicObject` is the parent to all classes `BasicObject`'s eigenclass is `Class` e.g. `BasicObject.singleton_class #> <Class:BasicObject>`

Comment: Your question is confusing. 1) In the title you ask about classes to do not inherit from `Class`, in the text, you ask about classes that aren't instances of `Class`. Those are *two completely different things*. Which one are you asking about? 2) There are *no* classes that inherit from `Class` and there are *no* classes which are not instances of `Class`, so regardless of which of the two questions you actually mean, it is hard to answer, since you don't give any concrete examples.

Answer (score 2):

You can treat all classes are instances of `Class` in the Ruby world. Worth remembering that everything in ruby is an object, including classes. Yes `BasicObject` is the top parent class of all classes in Ruby. The class of `BasicObject` being `Class`, is not the same as the parent class of `BasicObject` is `Class`.

To demonstrate, assume that we have a class `Person` defined.

- `Person.new.class` is `Person`
- `Person.class` is `Class`
- `Person.superclass` is `Object`
- `Object.class` is `Class`
- `Object.superclass` is `BasicObject`
- `BasicObject.class` is `Class`
- `BasicObject.superclass` is `nil`

Proof of all classes in Ruby are in fact objects, you can get the object id of a class. `BasicObject.object_id`. In the general object-oriented context, a class of a class shouldn't make sense, unless classes are also objects.

Comment: Right, I have to be sure to keep the difference in mind between being an instance of a class vs a subclass of it. I guess it's just very surprising to me that class A can be a parent class of class B while also being an instance of class B. That means that class A ends up inheriting from itself, right? I would have imagined that this kind of circular inheritance would cause problems, but I guess not!

Comment: "That means that class A ends up inheriting from itself, right?" – No, it doesn't mean that, because, as you just said in the sentence before, inheritance and instance are two completely different things.

Answer (score 2):

As mind-bending as it sounds, it really is like that. `BasicObject` is a `Class` and `Class` is a `BasicObject`.

I don't think it's possible to express in ruby, so to make this work MRI [direcly creates internal structures for these few fundamental classes and wires them in this cyclical manner](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/24c4e6dec109e105c13bd4c1b7f7cd51e534a3c3/class.c#L545-L563).

```
void
Init_class_hierarchy(void)
{
    rb_cBasicObject = boot_defclass("BasicObject", 0);
    rb_cObject = boot_defclass("Object", rb_cBasicObject);
    rb_gc_register_mark_object(rb_cObject);

    /* resolve class name ASAP for order-independence */
    rb_set_class_path_string(rb_cObject, rb_cObject, rb_fstring_lit("Object"));

    rb_cModule = boot_defclass("Module", rb_cObject);
    rb_cClass =  boot_defclass("Class",  rb_cModule);

    rb_const_set(rb_cObject, rb_intern_const("BasicObject"), rb_cBasicObject);
    RBASIC_SET_CLASS(rb_cClass, rb_cClass);
    RBASIC_SET_CLASS(rb_cModule, rb_cClass);
    RBASIC_SET_CLASS(rb_cObject, rb_cClass);
    RBASIC_SET_CLASS(rb_cBasicObject, rb_cClass);
}
```

As we can see, there are no two class types, user-facing one and "deep" one. It's the same entity.